# How to request that the role of my discord bot becomes the first in the server hierarchy?

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot with Discord js and it has to distribute roles according to the time a person has been connected.The problem is that even though I have administrator privileges, since the role puts itself automatically at the bottom of the server's role hierarchy, when I try to give a role it tells me that the bot does not have enough permissions. Here is a capture:

[image]

And I get an interruption due to lack of permissions when trying to assign the habitual role having PASM. Although PASM has administrator permissions and habitual role only some basic permission, I get this interruption.

Answer (score 0):

In that same exact page, you can hover over the `PASM` role and drag it above the role you want by dragging the 6 dots drag icon that shows up on the left of the role name.

Comment: a picture is worth a thousand words - by sharing an image you could help so much

Comment: You don't need an image because I understand what you're saying, but I already knew that before. The problem is that the bot has to do it automatically. Maybe with OAuth2 but there is no interest in doing it by hand.